# Azure B2C: Purpose of socialIdpUserId (or issuerUserId) claim

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

While looking through the [Azure B2C Custom Policy Starter Pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack), I noticed that the claim named `socialIdpUserId` is declared in the [LocalAccount's Base Framework file](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml), but was never used anywhere else in the file or the files that inherit from it.  However, I did a search in the repository and it was being used similarly to `issuerUserId`.

I'm wondering, was `socialIdpUserId` originally what `issuerUserId` is now?  If so, how come there's no mention of `socialIdpUserId` or `issuerUserId` (unless in examples) in the Azure B2C documentation?

Comment: See this https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/27602 and https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/25488

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`socialIdpUserId` got renamed to `issuerUserId`. It should always map to the claim name from the federated IdP that presents the users unique identifier, for example, objectId.

The purpose of `issuerUserId` is to allow the user to be mapped from the federated IdP to the user created inside the AAD B2C directory that represents this user.

You will see that the `issuerUserId` gets combined with the `identityProvider` claim to create an `alternativeSecurityId`. This combination of claims allows us to always map a specific user from a federated IdP to a specific user in the B2C directory.

I will document this soon ;)